# MongoDB + NodeJS: MapReduce or manual calculation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mapreduce

I am creating a REST API in NodeJS that connects to MongoDB does a MapReduce and store the results on a different collection.

The code is pretty simple. It takes a User ID, gets all other users who are related to this user somehow using some algorithm, and then for each one, calculate a likeness percentage. Assuming there are 50k users in the test database, this MapReduce takes around 200-800ms. And that is ideal for me. If this were to get famous and have hundreds of concurrent requests like this, I'm pretty sure that will not be the case any more. I understand that MongoDB might need to be sharded as needed.

The other scenario is to just do a normal find(), loop over the cursor and do the same logic. It takes the same amount of time as MapReduce mind you. However, I just thought about this to try and put the heavy lifting of the calculations on the client side (NodeJS) and not on the server side like MapReduce. Does this idea even have merit? I thought that this way, I can scale APIs horizontally behind a load balancer or something.

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to keep heavy lifting off of the server which processes each request and put it onto the database.

If you have 1000 requests and 200 of them require you to perform the calculation, 800 requests can be processed as normal by the server, so long as mongo does the the calculation with mapReduce or aggregation.

If you instead run the calculations manually on your node server, all requests will be affected by the server having to do the heavy lifting.

Mongo is also quite efficient at aggregation for sure and mapReduce also I would imagine.

I recently moved a ton of logic from my server onto mongoDB where I could and it made a world of difference.